# Mutt: select multiple messages

Tags: mutt

I am looking for a way to select multiple messages in Mutt.

For example, selecting the first and the last message would select a whole block of messages. I'd also like to select a subject using a regular expression.

Then, I want to run a command on the selected messages, e.g., save them to a file.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to run the `tag-pattern` command.  The default for that is `T` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).  You can then give it a regular expression.  By default this will match message subjects.

If you need to select a range of messages by number, you can provide the `~m [MIN]-[MAX]` pattern to tag-pattern.  There are many other options I've found useful over the years, and you can see a complete list in the [“Advanced Usage - Patterns” section of the manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual.html#patterns).

You can also use <kbd>t</kbd> to tag or untag the highlighted message, to fine-tune the selection.

Then you can run `tag-prefix` (<kbd>;</kbd>) followed by `save-message` (<kbd>s</kbd>), and it will prompt you for a mailbox name. This command marks the saved messages to be deleted; there is also the `copy-message` command (`C`, i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+c) to copy without marking for deletion.

Comment: to select all: `T` then dot (`.`)

Comment: If you want to delete multiple messages based on a pattern, you can hit `D` and then type a pattern (like `spam@spam.spa`).  Then quit and purge.

Comment: After running the command on the tagged (selected) messages, the messages are still tagged. To **de**select (untag) all messages, use `Ctrl` + `t`, then  dot (`.`).

Answer (score 11):

Extending [@Scott McClung's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115321/179901) correct answer:

If you want to apply mutt commands by default to all selected (tagged) messages without using `tag-prefix` (bound to `;` by default), you can set the `auto_tag` variable by adding this line to your `.muttrc`:

```
set auto_tag = yes
```

Comment: `true` was not accepted by my mutt version 1.10.1 and it pointed out that values should either be `yes` or `no`. would edit it but it's too short of an edit for SE to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Check also http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/mutt/manual-4.html + http://www.rosipov.com/blog/effective-search-with-mutt/ for useful flags like `~d 31/12/99-01/01/00 ~s Y2K ~b scared`.

`L` uses the same syntax to browse only a subset of your inbox, eg `~f moms.email@debian.org ~B your father`.

Comment: loved the samples :-)